# How to manage users based on roles using angular and lambda and aws cognito?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have created an angular 7 app with lambda services for the apis. This has user registration and login process. I want to manage users based on roles(eg. Admin, Super admin, user, technician etc.) using cognito. How do I achieve that?